# get values from three tables in sql

Tags: sql

I have three tables like below

tbl_asset_reg

```
barcode   | emp_id         |port_id     |floor
----------|----------------|------------|------
 1        | emp1           | 0          |7th
 2        | 0              | 12         |20th
 3        | emp2           | 0          |5th
```

tbl_asset_Transfer

```
barcode   | emp_id         |port_id     |floor
----------|----------------|------------|------
 1        | emp3           | 0          |20th
 2        | 0              | 12         |20th
 4        | emp2           | 0          |5th
```

tbl_employee

```
emp_id    | emp_name        company       |department
----------|----------------|--------------|------
 emp1     | sa             | abc          |finance
 emp2     | ra             | cdf          |finance
 emp3     | rom            | abc          |it
```

i want to get all barcodes and details from  tbl_asset_Transfer left outer joining with tbl_asset_reg.my problem is when i get the result by left outer joining how to get corresponding emp_name and company from tbl_employee. Please help

Comment: which DBMS are you doing this on?

Comment: i am using oracle.please tell me a way to do this

Comment: thanks for formatting my post.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming some assets will not have an employee assigned (emp_ID = 0)

```
SELECT * 
from tbl_Asset_Transer tat
LEFT JOIN tbl_asset_Reg tar
 ON tat.barcode = tar.barcode
LEFT JOIN tblEmployee TE
 on (TE.Emp_ID = Tar.Emp_ID and TE.Emp_ID=tat.empID)
 OR (TE.Emp_ID = tat.emp_ID and tat.empID is null)
```

Though this seems ugly may be better to union asset tables first then join since they apear to have same structure just depends on the output your looking for.

Comment: it does not give the employee name,company and department.those are null.