# SQL inner join and outer join

Tags: sql

Below is my query

```
SELECT
    trt.barcode,
    trt.emp_id,
    et.emp_name,
    trt.port_id,
    rt.emp_id,
    et.emp_name,
    rt.port_id,
    rt.`floor`,
    trt.`floor`
FROM tbl_employee et 
INNER JOIN tbl_trns as trt 
   on et.emp_id= trt.emp_id 
left outer join tbl_reg as rt 
   on trt.barcode = rt.barcode 
inner join et 
   on rt.emp_id=et.emp_id;
```

What is the problem in this query? It does not give a unique table/alias error.

Comment: don't use `et` again, try to use `inner join tbl_employee et2` instead of `inner join et`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the alias `et` twice. Change one of them to make them unique

Comment: but i want to get the result from same table.that is why i used it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726367/get-values-from-three-tables-in-sql?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

The first table you list is `tbl_employee` an you give it the alias `et`. the last table you use is a table called `et`. I assume you are trying to join back to the same table. you can use the same table twice but you need to give it a different alias each time. Or alternatively you can use a Common table Expression if your RDMS supports it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is appropriate. Notice this block of your code:

```
FROM tbl_employee et 
INNER JOIN tbl_trns as trt 
   on et.emp_id= trt.emp_id 
left outer join tbl_reg as rt 
   on trt.barcode = rt.barcode 
inner join et
```

See that tbl_employee is named `et` and then last line in the above block is also `et`. Name tbl_employee `et1` or `emp`.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct one.

```
SELECT
    trt.barcode,
    trt.emp_id,
    et.emp_name,
    trt.port_id,
    rt.emp_id,
    et.emp_name,
    rt.port_id,
    rt.`floor`,
    trt.`floor`
FROM tbl_employee et 
INNER JOIN tbl_trns as trt 
   on et.emp_id= trt.emp_id 
left outer join tbl_reg as rt 
   on trt.barcode = rt.barcode 
 AND rt.emp_id=et.emp_id;
```

for more info click: http://www.kanzulashya.com/oralce-join/equi-join/